# Java call inherited methods using only one object

Tags: java

How to call methods of 2 classes (inherited) using just the object of any one class.
Consider the code

```java
class Employee
{
    void display()
    {
        System.out.println("Name of class is Employee");
    }

    void calcSalary()
    {
        System.out.println("Salary of employee is 10000");
    }
}

class Engineer extends Employee
{
    void display()
    {
        System.out.println("Name of class is Engineer");
    }
    void calcSalary()
    {
        System.out.println("Salary of engineer is 20000");
    }
}
```

If I declare an object as

```java
Employee ob = new Employee();
ob.display();  //prints "Name of class is Employee"
ob.calcSalary(); //prints "Salary of employee is 10000"
```

Similarly

```java
Engineer ob = new Engineer();
ob.display();  //prints "Name of class is Engineer"
ob.calcSalary();  //prints "Salary of engineer is 20000"
```

How do I get all these 4 outputs using only a single instance (of either class) ?

Comment: You could some fine technical answers, but all miss the point of first asking: **why** do you want to do that? Remember that *inheritance* means: an Engineer is supposed to be an Employee.

Answer (score 1):

You could add calls to the super class methods in your `Engineer` class:

```
class Engineer extends Employee
{
    void display()
    {
        super.display();
        System.out.println("Name of class is Engineer");
    }
    void calcSalary()
    {
        super.calcSalary();
        System.out.println("Salary of engineer is 20000");
    }
}
```

Then calling the 2 methods for an `Engineer` instance will print all 4 outputs:

```
Engineer ob = new Engineer();
ob.display(); 
ob.calcSalary();
```

Answer (score 1):

by adding `super.display()` in first line of inhereted method you can call the parent calss's method.

Comment: And how does that help?

Comment: it will call the super class method initialization before inhereted one.

Comment: I do know that. I am just asking the more philosophical question "what kind of problem gets solved here".

Comment: calling body implementation of parent and child classes.

Comment: I do understand that. You want to read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem ... you are answering a "Y" question, but I think it might be relevant to figure why the OP asked *that* quesiton.

Answer (score 1):

if you use like this this

```
Employee ob = new Engineer(); //Using Ploymorphism 
ob.display();  //prints "Name of class is Engineer"
ob.calcSalary();  //prints "Salary of engineer is 20000"
```

It will still call its sub class methods as the methods of the parent class are overriden in child class. To get out of this situation you just change the name of or overload methods like in this way

```
class Employee
{
void displayEmp()
{
    System.out.println("Name of class is Employee");
}

void calcSalaryEmp() 
{
    System.out.println("Salary of employee is 10000");
}
}

class Engineer extends Employee
{
void display()
{
    System.out.println("Name of class is Engineer");
}
void calcSalary()
{
    System.out.println("Salary of engineer is 20000");
}
}
Employee ob = new Engineer(); //Using Ploymorphism 
ob.displayEmp(); //will display emp 
ob.calcSalaryEmp() //will display emp salary 
ob.display();  //prints "Name of class is Engineer"
ob.calcSalary();  //prints "Salary of engineer is 20000"
```

Now you are able to access both the parent and child using single object